# Pug - как закомментировать атрибут?

Tags: javascript, jade, pug

Я использую `vuejs + pug + webpack`, и у меня встала такая проблема.

Есть пачка блоков, которые выводятся в цикле, примерно так:

```
.form-field(v-for="field in fields", v-if="field.value != undefined")
     input ... итд...
```

Мне понадобилось временно убрать условие, но так, чтоб другие разработчики (например я через неделю) без гита увидели, что оно там должно быть. Вот так не работает:

- `div.form-field(v-for="field in fields",
  // v-if="field.value != undefined"
  )`
- `div.form-field(v-for="field in fields",/* v-if="field.value != undefined" */)`
- `div.form-field(v-for="field in fields")// ,v-if="field.value != undefined")`
  Вот так комментируется всё, что внутри блока
- `div.form-field(v-for="field in fields") // ,v-if="field.value != undefined")`
  Коммент выводится как текст
- `div.form-field(v-for="field in fields")/* ,v-if="field.value != undefined")*/`
- `div.form-field(v-for="field in fields") /*,v-if="field.value != undefined")*/`

Вот так я сделал в итоге:

```
// div.form-field(v-for="field in fields", v-if="field.value != undefined")
div.form-field(v-for="field in fields")
```

Comment: https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/2209

Comment: не первый атрибут можно блочно закомментить вроде бы

Comment: Видимо правильный ответ на мой вопрос - никак. с блочным комментированием есть одна небольшая проблема - блок комментируется)

Comment: там просто в issue воркэраунд с блочным комментом, но чет он у меня тоже не заработал